# Hibernate throwing "Bad version number in .class file" error

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public class HibernateTest {

     private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

     public static void main(String ars[]){

         UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
         user.setUserId(1);
         user.setUserName("First user");

         SessionFactory sessionFactory = configureSessionFactory(); 
         Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
         session.beginTransaction();
         session.save(user);
         session.getTransaction().commit();     
     }

//using Hibernate API
     private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {

         Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         configuration.configure();
         serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
         sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
         return sessionFactory;
     }  
 }
```

**ERROR**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at hibernate.HibernateTest.configureSessionFactory(HibernateTest.java:30)
at hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:20)
```

I'm Hibernate beginner. Can anybody explain me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Java are you running?

Comment: It is not a Hibernate problem, is your JVM version prior to 5? Hibernate 4 does not work with JVM with versions before 5, I'm not sure, but maybe hibernate 4 just works with JVM 6+

Answer (score 0):

This:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class

basically means that the version of Java you're using is too old for the code you're trying to run.

Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I m using java version 5 and Hibernate version 4.0.1 final

Comment: @Rizwana: Hmm. Maybe Hibernate 4.0.1 was built targeting Java 6 - I can't find system requirements in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It is `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file`

It seems you are having wrong version of hibernate jar which are not supported by your runtime (jvm).

Answer (score 0):

Check the JDK version of the hibernate class using following command

javap -verbose org.hibernate.SessionFactory.SessionFactory

(first unzip the jar)

Make sure that your HibernateTest is also compiled in the same version.